# Was trying to refactor code and not sure where I am going wrong?

Tags: javascript

Original code i wrote for first pset which was to lower case and "whipser":

```
function whisper(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase();
}
```

my most recent function which is bouncing between lower and uppercase but the t in test stays lowercase. Getting confused:

```
function alternatingLetters(str) {
  const arr = str.split("");
  let isUpper = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== " ") {
      arr[i] = isUpper ? arr[i].toUpperCase() : arr[i].toLowerCase();
      isUpper = !isUpper;
    }
  }

  return arr.join("");
}
```

Error message I am getting:

```
AssertionError: expected 'tHiS iS a TeSt' to equal 'tHiS Is a tEsT'
      + expected - actual

      -tHiS iS a TeSt
      +tHiS Is a tEsT
```

Any tips would be great! I also tried to make a version without a loop and just return like original solution but not sure if that can be done!

Comment: Looks like you need to remove the condition for `if (arr[i] !== " ") {`

Comment: What does this have to do with refactoring? Your original code was doing dsomething completely different (lowercasing the entire string). Refactoring is when you rearrange code without changing the result (usually to make it clearer, more efficient, or easier to enhance in the future).

Comment: Who knew that deleting an if statement would result in 4+ answers

Answer (score 1):

One solution is moving the `isUpper` flag outside the `if` condition.

```js
function alternatingLetters(str) {
  const arr = str.split("");
  let isUpper = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== " ") {
      arr[i] = isUpper ? arr[i].toUpperCase() : arr[i].toLowerCase();
    }
    isUpper = !isUpper;
  }

  return arr.join("");
}

console.log(alternatingLetters('this is a test'));
```

Comment: Or just get rid of the `if` entirely. There's no harm in calling the case changing functions on non-letters.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes this is a possible solution too.

Answer (score 1):

> I also tried to make a version without a loop and just return like original solution but not sure if that can be done!

Not just with a standard string function (like `toLowerCase()`), but can be done with `map`:

```js
function alternatingLetters(str) {
  const arr = str.split("");

  return arr.map(
    (character, i) => (i % 2 === 0)
        ? character.toLowerCase()
        : character.toUpperCase()
  ).join('');
}

console.assert(alternatingLetters('this is a test') === 'tHiS Is a tEsT');
```

Comment: This is beautiful

Answer (score 1):

```
function alternatingLetters(str) {
  const arr = str.split("");
  let isUpper = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== " ") {
      arr[i] = isUpper ? arr[i].toUpperCase() : arr[i].toLowerCase();
    }
    isUpper = !isUpper;
  }
  return arr.join("");
}
```

try to `isUpper = !isUpper;` outside of if block.

Answer (score 0):

I clearly misunderstood the question. The function in the following snippet flips the case of each character in the string:

```js
function upsideDown(s){
 s=s.split("");
 for (let i=0;i<s.length; i++){
  let t=s[i].toLowerCase();
  s[i]=t==s[i]?s[i].toUpperCase():t;
 }
 return s.join("");
}

console.log(upsideDown("This Is a cRaZy TeSt!"))
```

Comment: That is not the same... produces a totally different output.